# Using unique user identifier in Django logs

Tags: django

In my website I'd like to add logging of user actions (eg. user added/modified/deleted something, user visited some page, user logged-in/out). Just to be clear I'd need this identifier be unique but allow me to follow user and not change on every site (everything happens within my website).

I have already logger in place, but I'm not sure how I can get unique user identifier. Currently it looks like this:

```
logger.info('User %s entered website X', self.request.user)
```

I know I could use `request.user` for logged-in users, but what with the rest? Right now everyone are `AnonymousUser`, but instead I'd like to have some unique identifier.

I assume Django is already providing that, but question is - how I could access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anonymous users I'd set my own session ID

When SessionMiddleware is activated, each HttpRequest object – the first argument to any Django view function – will have a session attribute, which is a dictionary-like object.

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views

```
import uuid

request.session['anonymous_id'] = uuid.uuid4()

# Then you can do
logger.info('User %s entered website X', request.session['anonymous_id'])
```

How you decide to set this sesssion attribute is up to you, I'd suggest a middleware approach where you check, is the users logged in. If not then check if there is already a session id. If not then set one.

Comment: Thanks!, That is exactly what I needed.